# How do I create a url with a bookmark?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to have a link to the knowledge base but I want to also create the bookmark using the id attribute.

```
// var url = "/KnowledgeBase/Index#Bookmark"
```

so in my view I want to add that bookmark using the value from my model

```
var url = Url.Content(string.Concat(Url.Action("Index", "KnowledgeBase"), "#", Model.Bookmark));
```

This doesn't seem elegant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "KnowledgeBase")#Bookmark">TextLink</a>
```

Comment: I was trying to build the entire url all ahead of time in a code block, by tacking the bookmark on in anchor itself is much better and more elegant. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
@Html.Action("Index","KnowledgeBase",new{id= Model.Bookmark})
```

or you have to redirect using  `script`

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action( "Index", "KnowledgeBase" )?id='+@Model.Bookmark
```

Comment: wouldn't that create a url that looks like /KnowledgeBase/Index/Bookmark, I want the #